# Template based get component method fails on inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, components

Edit: The problem described below is incorrect, the code is in fact functional. However I'd still like to improve on the getComponent method, as dynamic_cast is certainly pretty slow.

Thanks

In the game engine I have developed I have a Component based system similar to Unity's. The GetComponent method is as follows:

```
template <typename CompType>
inline CompType getComponent()
{
    for(Component * currComp : components)
    {
        CompType currentEntry = dynamic_cast<CompType>(currComp);
        if (currentEntry != nullptr)
        {
            return currentEntry;
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

I have a problem however.

```
class SomeComponent : public Component
{//Some class};

class SomeSpecialComponent: public SomeComponent
{//Some specialized version of the above class};

someObject.addComponent(new SomeComponent());

someObject.addComponent(new SomeSpecialComponent());

//This could retrieve either component
SomeComponent * sc1 = someObject.getComponent<SomeComponent*>();

//This fails
SomeComponent * sc1 = someObject.getComponent<SomeSpecialComponent*>();
```

How can I redesign this method to ensure the correct component is being returned?

Thanks

Comment: I can't answer your question because I don't really get what you want to do. But what I can say is that `dynamic_cast` already is a sign of bad design, now you also want abuse `dynamic_cast` for a even worse thing? I guess no matter what you trying to solve, there is a much better solution.

Comment: dynamic_cast in this case is allowing my template method to work with components that it doesn't #include. In a game engine this is very useful - it could be used with components not included in the original engine. I don't know of any other method of implementing this. Dynamic_cast is often, but not always bad - and what part my question suggests in any way  I want to abuse it?

Comment: If you want to avoid `dynamic_cast` then you could store different components in different containers, one for each type. And other container for the types stored. Or gather it all in a `std::map`

Comment: But if my engine is designed to accept many types of component, some made separately to the engine, how could I create a container for each? Don't know much about std::map, do they allow me to differentiate between class types?

Comment: Going to ask a new question has the answer I'm needing has changed. Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some design issues here, but it's difficult to help because there is no approach for me to recreate your code. Maybe you could post all your functions which have to do with your problem, not only those you think they don't work properly.

But I will try my best. At first, as already mentioned your dynamic_cast is a bad design, because "GetComponent" will likely often get called and dynamic_cast's are really expensive. I would try using a base Component class, like Unity really does it. If you handle those Components like the most game engines does, with a base class from which you derive from, you have a lot more control and can optimize better than with your approach. You only have to write the base component class in your game engine and let all other classes derive from this class. If you provide the functions you really need in your engine code you won't have any problem with that. Then you only need to expose this class to the game which should get created with your engine.

If you need some example, download Unreal Engine source code which is open source and study a bit of it and I think you will learn a lot from that.

I would give the "addComponent" function a try or maybe the container you want to store the component, because maybe it checks if the component is already contained and if they have the same base class and the check isn't properly written, the container just never receives the class you want to add.

If you already checked that it would be nice to know how you detect, that your second function fails? Did you get a nullptr or did you get an error message? If you receive a nullptr out of the function try to debug your code and write a more detailed description of what happens here.

Comment: There is a base class Component. The getComponent method simply has to differentiate between different kinds of component, hence the use of dynamic cast to "check" if it is the requested type. The only other solution I can think of would be having a component manager and some sort of static ID assigned to each type of component but that screams clunky to me, and I wouldn't be able to pass in a class type as an argument like I currently can (correct me if I'm wrong). I would love to be able to ditch dynamic_cast but haven't yet found a better way to duplicate the Unity method.

Comment: I will download the unreal source code though, thanks for that advice. As for how I checked that the second function doesn't work, I was wrong, it does work.  I did answer my own question saying it did work but my answer was deleted. Still looking to replace dynamic_cast for reasons you've outlined though

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance is a "is a" relationship, so if `A` inherits from `B` and `C` from `B` it means `B` is a `A` and `C` is a `B`. So if you have an `C*`-object then the object behind `C*` literally also is a `B*` and a `A*`. There is no none hacky way to distinguish `new B()` and `new C()` object by `dynamic_cast`ing it to `B*`, because both of those types are a `B*`.

But one solution with a big drawback to your problem could be to declare your child classes as `final` and the parent classes with at least one pure virtual function. I guess the drawback is self explanatory.

Comment: The parent class does have a virtual function, I don't actually know the meaning of final in c++, how would this affect it? Thanks

Comment: Sorry I meant: "pure virtual function". The keyword `final` is just for the compiler to make sure, the compiler isn't compiling code which trys to inherite from classes declared as `final`. So there is no need for a `getComponent` call with a class type which isn't at the end of the iheritance hierachy. But like mentioned, you should change your class design, since your code suggests a really bad design.